# Permanently passing variable to function

Tags: php

Can someone help me simplify this code? Is there a way I can permanently pass $the_campus to is_campus() without using a global scope? $the_campus is pulling from a database and the value changes, but the variable is always called $the_campus.

Thanks!

```
 $the_campus = $search_term['campus'];
    function is_campus($the_campus, $selected_campus) {
        if ( $selected_campus == $the_campus ) {
            echo 'selected';
        }
    }

    <?php is_campus($the_campus, 'university-of-minnesota-tc'); ?>
    <?php is_campus($the_campus, 'university-of-wisconsin'); ?>
    <?php is_campus($the_campus, 'university-of-chicago'); ?>
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use the global scope? That's pretty much the only way this is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might devise a way of passing the variable without explicitly writing `global` in your function, but please do not. The function is just fine as it is; introducing "invisible" coupling with a variable is going to make your code *worse*, not better.

What you *would* probably want to do is refactor the code so that it works in an equivalent manner but is more straightforward to use, for example:

```
function echo_campus_string($the_campus, array $campuses) { 
    foreach($campuses as $campus) {
        if($campus == $the_campus) {
            echo 'selected'; // you will probably want to make the output more involved
            // perhaps break as well?
        }
    }
} 

<?php echo_campus_string($the_campus, array('university-of-minnesota-tc', '...', '...')); ?>
```

Comment: I really like this approach. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

While I won't ultimately recommend this:

```
class CCampushelper {

  // will be found by reference
  protected $campus;

  public
  function bindVariable( &$externalCampus ) {

     $this->campus =& $externalCampus;

  }

  public
  function is_campus( $selected_campus) {

    if ( $selected_campus === $this->campus ) {
       echo 'selected';
    }

  }

}
```

Call this somewhere early:

```
$helper = new CCampushelper();
$helper->bindVariable( $campuses );
```

And later on this:

```
<?php $helper->is_campus( 'university-of-minnesota-tc' ); ?>
<?php $helper->is_campus( 'university-of-wisconsin' ); ?>
<?php $helper->is_campus( 'university-of-chicago' ); ?>
```

Comment: I like this approach too, but I don't think I'm going to create an entire object because I'm only using this once or twice.

Comment: Thx! At least, this approach how to use reference variables.